# Can every weakly converging sequence be made to converge strongly after taking a subsequence and rearranging?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis

Let $f_i: [0, 1] \to \mathbb R$ be functions in $L^1 \cap L^\infty$ with $\sup_i \|f_i\|_{L^\infty} < M$ for some $M > 0$.

Suppose $f_i$ converge weakly in $L^1$ to some $L^1$ function $f$ - that is, $\int f_i g \ d\mu \to \int fg \ d\mu$ for all $g \in L^\infty$.

> **Question:** Does there exist a subsequence $f_{n_k}$, and measure preserving bijections $T_k: [0, 1] \to [0, 1]$ such that $f_{n_k} \circ T_k$ converges strongly in $L^1?$ (Not necessarily to $f$)

Comment: What do you mean by weak-$*$ convergence in $L^1$?

Comment: Sorry, I mean that $\int f_i g \ d\mu \to \int fg \ d\mu$ for all $g \in L^\infty$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! This is actually called weak (rather than weak-$*$) convergence.

Comment: Ah, sorry my bad. I will modify it, and also write the definition in the original post.

Comment: Isn't any set of decreasing uniformly bounded functions pre-compact in $L^1$?

Comment: @fedja Oh, I think that is true - in that case we just rearrange all the $f_i$ to be decreasing and we are done then.

Comment: "Rearrange to be decreasing" ... That is not $f \circ T$ as in the OP.  For example, $f(x) = 4x(1-x)$ in $[0,1]$ where each value in $(0,1)$ occurs twice.  How do we "rearrange" it to be decreasing?  We cannot use measure-preserving bijection for that.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar: WLOG the functions are simple functions.